# Django - display value of an @property field in a filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Good evening guys, I have the following model structure in my project:

`

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_name = models.TextField()
    foo_city = models.TextField()
    foo_actions = models.ManyToManyField(Action, through="FooActions")

@property
    def bar(self):
        response = True if FooAction.objects.filter(
            foo_id=self.pk,
            foo__action=Action.ACTION_NAME_PK).first() else False
        return response
```

`

I need to bring the 'bar' field in a filter, but I'm not getting it.

I tried as follows:

`Foo.objects.filter(nome="João").values("foo_city","bar")`

Is it possible to bring this information this way?

PS.: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Sorry, but it is not, as a property is not a value on itself, but rather a function that is called each time you use the property. Thus a property cannot be used for a db query.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible directly because @property method interacts with a model's objects it is not a field of model

the model field is a column of the data table but, @property method interacts with a model column I mean it's not part of the SQL query

but you can achieve those things using a third-party library.
refer to this PyPI package link [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-property-filter/)